# How can I pass a value from a TeamCity failure Condition to an e-mail notification?

Tags: kotlin, teamcity

I want to show the status of the build in an e-mail with just a simple FAIL or PASS text appear in the body. There does not seem to be any kind of predefined "buildStatus" variable that I can access or setup in TeamCity. I guess I need to access the "failureConditions" function at bottom but not sure how, tried lots of things but nothing worked, this is my script:

```
package _Self.buildTypes

import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.failureConditions.BuildFailureOnText
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.failureConditions.failOnText
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.triggers.schedule

allowExternalStatus = true
params {
param("MinorVersion", "0")
param("RevisionVersion", "0")
```

}

```
powerShell {
        name = "Email"
        scriptMode = script {
            content = """
                function Send-ToEmail([string]${'$'}email, [string]${'$'}attachmentpath){
                
                    ${'$'}message = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage;
                    ${'$'}message.From = "teamcity@blog.com";
                    ${'$'}message.To.Add(${'$'}email);
                    ${'$'}message.Subject = "%env.TEAMCITY_PROJECT_NAME% | %VersionNumber% ";
                    ${'$'}message.Body = "The build: PASS or FAIL text here";
                    
                    ${'$'}smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient("blog.local", "25");
                    ${'$'}smtp.EnableSSL = ${'$'}true;
                    ${'$'}smtp.send(${'$'}message);
                    write-host "Mail Sent" ; 
                 }
                Send-ToEmail -email "me@blog.com" -attachmentpath ${'$'}path;
            """.trimIndent()
        }
    }
}

failureConditions {
    failOnText {
        conditionType = BuildFailureOnText.ConditionType.CONTAINS
        pattern = "FAIL"
        reverse = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this in T/C:

1. Create new custom env. var. e.g. `MyBuildStatus`
2. Create new build step e.g. `Set build status` (only executes if build successful)
3. Create a new Parameter name='env.MyBuildStatus.Status' value='SUCCESS'
4. Add variable to email subject: $message.Subject = "%env.MyBuildStatus.Status%

Why T/C has no build in "buildstatus" env. variable is interesting.